# LINQ: Foreach loop on a query causing unexpected results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

So  I have this query, which should return a record if there is a matching word in query with either of first name, last name or the phone number:

```
var searchWords = searchQuery
                .Split(' ')
                .Select(x => x.Trim()
                .ToLower())
                .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)).ToArray();

foreach (var searchWord in searchWords)
        {
            var word = searchWord;
            someParentObjects= someParentObjects
            .Where(x => x.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
            x.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
            x.User.CellPhone.Contains(word) 
            );
        }
```

Somehow the contains match is not working, as a result I am getting zero results? Why is that?

**Note:**  The first part is working fine, I am able to get trimmed words from  the searchQuery.

**Test Data**:
Basically all I want to do is that filter the results based on the query. If there is any word in the query matching with any of first name, last name or cell phone, I will return those records. So If I  have a record in my db where first name is "James" and last name is "Brian", if I pass the query as "James Something" it should return a record. But it is not returning. I am getting zero records.

Comment: Make sure to provide sample data that shows the problem.

Comment: To make things easier, you could add a second argument to your string.Split of StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries that will remove empty strings from the results.

Comment: `String.Contains` is not `IEnumerable<T>.Contains`

Comment: what are `patientSteps`? please show the class definition and how these are built or retrieved.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot while your comment is true, I don't see that it is relevant.  In what way do you suspect the OP of confusing 'String.Contains` and 'Enumerable.Contains`?

Comment: The issue is with the way I am using foreach loop with my where clause, can you guys think of any other way to do it?

Comment: @Obviously Do you get "James" in your searchWords array?? Your code seems to be fine. If the searchQuery contains a string like "James John Doe" then searchWords first element will be "James" and the rest seems to be fine

Comment: Yes, I get it in searchWords. That part is working fine.

Comment: @phoog I don't suspect it's the cause of his issue, but he's tagged the question as LINQ related (and included it in the title), which it isn't.

Comment: @Obviously please update title of your post to match accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping a linq statement with a foreach loop is usually a sign of something gone wrong. Linq is already doing the 'loop' part for you.

```
var searchWords = searchQuery
                .Split(new char[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Trim().ToUpper())
                .ToArray();
```

Here, we reverse the search logic to use contains with Any() and Linq takes care of the enumeration for us.

```
var result = (from step in patientSteps
              where searchWords.Any(x => 
              step.User.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(x) ||
              step.User.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(x) ||
              step.User.CellPhone.Contains(x) )
              select step);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code essentially filtering for all "searchWords" to be present in at least one of the fields. Most likely for multiple words such filtering returns no results.

Simplified version of your `foreach` for search terms "Bob John" and patient "John Doe":

```
var filtered = new[]{"John"}
 .Where(firstName => firstName.Contains("Bob"))
 .Where(firstName => firstName.Contains("John"));
```

While it is not exactly clear what you looking for, but possibly stopping on a first non-empty result is an option:

```
    foreach (var searchWord in searchWords)
    {
        var word = searchWord;
        var filteredPatientSteps = patientSteps
        .Where(x => x.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
        x.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
        x.User.CellPhone.Contains(word) 
        );
        if (filteredPatientSteps.Any())
        {
             // jump out on first match 
            patientSteps = filteredPatientSteps;
            break;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I think you know what is wrong with my query, So  is there any other way by which I can introduce a foreach loop for my where clause?

Comment: @Obviously I have no idea what you *actually* trying to do with your filtering so I can't even guess how to change your code.

Comment: I am trying to get words from a search Query and trying to result a record if any of the word matches with eith of first name, last name or cell phone number.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get "James" in your searchWords array?? Your code seems to be fine. If the searchQuery contains a string like "James John Doe" then searchWords first element will be "James" and the rest seems to be fine. I have tired it as:

```
var searchQuery = "John Doe Brazil";

            var searchWords = searchQuery
                .Split(' ')
                .Select(x => x.Trim()
                    .ToLower())
                .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)).ToArray();
            User obj=new User()
            {
                FirstName = "Ali",
                LastName = "John"
            };
            var someParentObjects =new[]{ new Parent(){Users =obj}};


            foreach (var searchWord in searchWords)
            {
                var word = searchWord;
              var ParentObjects = someParentObjects
                .Where(x => x.Users.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
                x.Users
                .LastName.ToLower().Contains(word) 

                );
            }
```

where I have taken User and Parent to be:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public User Users { get; set; }
    public Parent() { }

}
```

The ParentObjects in this case returns the object Ali John.

**Edit:**
To usethe ParentObjects outside loop do something like:

```
List<Parent> ParentObjects=new List<Parent>();

            foreach (var searchWord in searchWords)
            {
                var word = searchWord;
               var ParentObject = someParentObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Users.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(word) ||
                                                                        x.Users
                                                                            .LastName.ToLower().Contains(word));
                if(ParentObject!=null)
                ParentObjects.Add(ParentObject);
            }
```

ParentObjects can then be used outside the loop.

Comment: @Obviously the only other problem if your searchQuery and searchWords are fine as you say could be that you are having mismatched objects in someParentObjects . There can be no other problem that I can think of.

Comment: In your code you are creating a new  object  ParentObjects for each instance  of the  foreach loop. Which is wrong i guess?

Comment: But this way I will only be getting first element for each searchWord, I want all the results/records for each search word

Comment: @Obviously No, you will get only results for those searhword that match with someParentObjects(the Linq query result) i.e where ParentObject !=null. If you want all just remove the if check. That way all those that will match will return a Parent Object but for the ones who don't a null value would be added to the ParentObjects list. Plus it would be better if you show what your desired output should be to help better understand what you want but I think that would be a separate question altogether. The LINQ query that you showed was ok which answers your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough to create reproduction, but your existing code seems to work if I fill in the rest.

```
void Main() {
    string searchQuery = "foo bar";
    IEnumerable<PatientStep> patientSteps = new PatientStep[] {
        new PatientStep("foo", "bar", "12345"),
        new PatientStep("foo", "williams", "12345"),
        new PatientStep("nancy", "bar", "12345"),
        new PatientStep("nothing", "relevant", "12345"),
    };

    var searchWords = searchQuery
                    .Split(' ')
                    .Select(x => x.Trim()
                        .ToLower())
                    .Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y)).ToArray();

    foreach (var searchWord in searchWords) {
        var word = searchWord;
        patientSteps = patientSteps.Where(
            x => x.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(word)
                || x.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(word)
                || x.User.CellPhone.Contains(word)
        );
    }

    foreach (var patientStep in patientSteps) {
        Console.WriteLine(patientStep.ToString());
    }
}

class PatientStep {
    public User User { get; private set; }

    public PatientStep(string first, string last, string cell) {
        this.User = new User { FirstName = first, LastName = last, CellPhone = cell };
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", this.User.FirstName, this.User.LastName, this.User.CellPhone);
    }
}

class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

This produces the output:

```
foo bar, 12345
```